# Long response time when hosting tensorflow model flask app on server (gunicorn worker timeout)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, flask

I have this simple flask app that lets you upload a png (captcha), and predict the text. It's loading a custom CTC layer from an h5 file. I'm not sure if I'm loading the the CTCLayer correctly but it's working fine on my local machine. When I host this flask app on a server the prediciton response is taking a very long time and I end up getting the worker timeout error. Is there a problem in the approach of loading the model or is this related to having insufficient resources (CPU, GPU, etc)..?

Flask

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from ctc_layer import CTCLayer


app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png'}
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


img_width = 177
img_height = 40
max_length = 5
characters = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'e', 'p']


char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None
)


num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)


def encode_single_prediction(img_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=1)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
    img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    return img


def decode_single_prediction(pred):
    input_len = np.array([pred.shape[1]])
    results = tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]
    output_text = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(results[0])).numpy().decode("utf-8")
    return output_text


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], uploaded_file.filename)
    uploaded_file.save(temp_file_path)
    image = encode_single_prediction(temp_file_path)
    model = keras.models.load_model('trained_model.h5', custom_objects={'CTCLayer': CTCLayer})
    prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
        model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
    )
    prediction = prediction_model.predict(image)
    result = decode_single_prediction(prediction)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

CTCLayer class

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf


class CTCLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        return y_pred
```

Comment: Do you intend to reload the model each time you make a prediction? That's probably why the call takes time.

Comment: @jlandercy no and that was probably the problem, I need to only load the model once at the application startup. Thank you

Comment: A quick solution is to create the model at the module level and let the python scope makes the magic.